# click on button works for one time

Tags: android

i am trying to make a button work for only once, so i did this solution, but sometimes it keeps working for two or more clicks, how to solve that?

```
              Button bton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ajoutTroisDemi); 
         bton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
          @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
              v.setClickable(false);
              v.setEnabled(false);
                ajouter(v);
                Intent l = new Intent(ActivityTroisQuart.this,ActivityTroisDemi.class);
                startActivity(l);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données Enregistrées", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

        public void  ajouter(View v) {
            db.open();
          EditText     rm_26 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rm_26);
          String       rm_26_1ts = rm_26.getText().toString();
          SharedPreferences prefs4 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
          prefs4.edit().putString(Ordr, rm_26_1ts).commit();   
        int nb = prefs4.getInt(B, 0);              
            long id = prefs4.getLong(ID, 0);
            db.insertMMbreMenage1(id,rm_26_1ts);
               int test = nb-1;
               Editor editor = prefs4.edit();
               editor.putInt("nb", test);
               editor.commit();

            db.close();                     
            } 
 });
```

Comment: why v.setClickable(false); v.setEnabled(false); are not effective ???

Comment: Can you specify the case, When your button worked for twice ? Your code seems fine.

Comment: u can hide that button as well, or you can set a boolean Clicked = false, and when you click it once make it true and inside onclick have a if (click) { ....

Comment: @ user3110424: yes the code is fine, but when i click quickly on the button it works two times, it does that sometimes !

Comment: @ Rudi :  thanks for solution, may be that how i will proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do directly

```
final Button bton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ajoutTroisDemi);
bton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                bton.setEnabled(false);
                ajouter(v);
                Intent l = new Intent(ActivityTroisQuart.this,ActivityTroisDemi.class);
                startActivity(l);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données Enregistrées", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: so if i change v.setEnabled(false) to bton.setEnabled(false) it will solve the issue , could you explain more , thanks !

Comment: it didn't work, if you click quickly the button will execute twice!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code

```
bton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
          @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
              v.setClickable(false);
              v.setEnabled(false);
                ajouter(v);
                Intent l = new Intent(ActivityTroisQuart.this,ActivityTroisDemi.class);
                startActivity(l);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données Enregistrées", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
```

by

```
bton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
      @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          bton.setEnabled(false);
            Intent l = new Intent(ActivityTroisQuart.this,ActivityTroisDemi.class);
            startActivity(l);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données Enregistrées", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
```

your problem will be solved.

Comment: thanks, could you explain the difference, i have already this answer but i want to know why this one works and the other not !

Comment: because you tried to do this thing inside Button View , so it's controlled by the inside button operation, but Button bton is itself a Button object , which is itself a layout widget . So it's happen for bton not by Button view v

Comment: it didn't work, if you click quickly the button will execute twice!

Comment: means it's not disable the button?

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you use a condition statement to test if the Button is enabled of not after perfoming the requried task intented by the button.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can delete from your code those lines, your button become not clickable because of them.

```
      v.setClickable(false);
      v.setEnabled(false);
```

2. If you really need this methods. You can try to enable them after your code is done. Like this.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
              v.setClickable(false);
              v.setEnabled(false);
              ajouter(v);
              Intent l = new Intent(ActivityTroisQuart.this,ActivityTroisDemi.class);
              startActivity(l);
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données Enregistrées", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              v.setClickable(true);
              v.setEnabled(true);
             }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for responding :) my problem is that i want the button works only for one click , but even when i used the methods v.setClickable(false);  v.setEnabled(false); it happends that i get the button works more than one time , that's the issue